# Coprimes up to N

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, primes

Given a number `n >= 2`, output all the positive integers less than `n` where `gcd(n, k) == 1` (with `k` being any one of the output numbers).  Numbers of this sort are **coprime** to each other.

Example: `10` gives the output `[1, 3, 7, 9]` (in any form you like, as long as the numbers are unambiguously separated and in some sort of list).  The list cannot have duplicate entries and doesn't have to be sorted.

More test cases:

```
2 -> [1]
3 -> [1, 2]
6 -> [1, 5]
10 -> [1, 3, 7, 9]
20 -> [1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19]
25 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24]
30 -> [1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

We are also not counting numbers above `n` that are coprime to `n`, solely because I'm fairly certain there's infinite solutions.

Also note: Numbers that are coprime to each other are also said to be relatively prime or mutually prime to each other.

Comment: Do seperate strings (e.g. `1\n3\n`) count as valid output?

Comment: @devRicher that works, sure.

Comment: The intuition about there being an infinite number of numbers above n that are coprime to n feels correct to me. There are infinitely many primes, and a prime would be coprime with every number below it. Therefore, every prime greater than n (of which there are infinitely many) are also part of the coprime list.

Comment: @BrianJ Not just that. If **c** and **n** are coprimes, **c + kn** and **n** are also coprimes, for all integers **k**.

Comment: Fun fact: these are called [totatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totative).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
gÐṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/98ISHO5v@H25/1LTG/f//aCMdBWMdBTMdBUMDHQUjEDYFihjEAgA)

## How does this work?

```
gÐṂ  - (Monadic) Full program.

g    - Greatest common divisor.
 ÐṂ  - Keep the elements with minimum link value (i.e. those with GCD == 1)
       Note that this automatically creates the range [1, input] (inclusive).
```

### Proof of validity

Since we want to extract the coprimes only, the minimum value of the Greatest-Common-Divisors list *has* to be **1** for the `ÐṂ` trick to work. Let's prove that (in two different methods):

1. The implicitly generated range, \$[1, \text{input}]\$ contains \$1\$ and \$\gcd(1, x) = 1\:\:\forall\:\:x \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}\$. The greatest common divisor is always a strictly positive integer, hence \$1\$ is guaranteed to occur and will always be the minimum value.
2. Two consecutive positive integers are always coprime. Consider \$x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}\$, with \$y = x + 1\$. Then we take another positive integer \$k\$ such that \$k \mid x\$ and \$k \mid y\$.

   This implies that \$k \mid (y - x)\$, so \$k \mid (x + 1 - x)\$, thus \$k  \mid 1\$. The only positive integer to divide \$1\$ is \$1\$ itself, so it is guaranteed to appear in the list and will always be the minimum value.

Comment: You outgolfed Dennis in his own language after 9 months!

Comment: @Adám I am not sure whether `ÐṂ` existed back then, anyway I am quite satisfied with this one.

Comment: For the record, `DṂ` did exist, but it only worked for monads. The commit [implemented `Þ`, `ÐṂ`, `ÐṀ` for dyads](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/commit/4f93f632e983b2a53b8302d3389ef1f3b30b75cf) is dated May 9, 2017.

Comment: @Dennis I knew there'd be a good reason why you didn't have the 3-byte version. We were wondering about that in chat too, so thanks for the useful information!

Answer (score 67):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>61</s> 47 bytes

```python
lambda n:[k/n for k in range(n*n)if k/n*k%n==1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FYpLCoAgAAXXdYq3CTSEftQi8CTVwihDrFdI97dczGZmLDTmeJpr3Qw4Tr4i7B3g4YhgeOyCJaWz@EvpC2rdLDEdTEer0CkMCk2t0Cb639Rjnj3B8RVWUMr4AQ)

#### Background

Consider the [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) \$(Z_n, +_n, \cdot_n)\$. While this ring is usually defined using residue classes modulo \$n\$, it can also be thought of as the set \$Z_n = \{0, \dots, n - 1\}\$, where the addition and multiplication operators are defined by \$a +_n b = (a + b)\:\%\: n\$ and \$a \cdot_n b = a \cdot b\:\%\: n\$, where \$+,\:\cdot\text{, and } \%\$ denote the usual addition, multiplication, and modulo operators over the integers.

Two elements \$a\$ and \$b\$ of \$Z_n\$ are called mutual [multiplicative inverses modulo \$n\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) if \$a \cdot_n b = 1\:\%\:n\$. Note that \$1\:\%\:n = 1\$ whenever \$n > 1\$.

Fix \$n > 1\$ and let \$a\$ be a coprime of \$n\$ in \$Z_n\$. If \$a \cdot_n x = a \cdot_n y\$ for two elements \$x\$ and \$y\$ of \$Z_n\$, we have that \$a \cdot x\:\%\:n = a \cdot y\:\%\:n\$. This implies that \$a \cdot (x - y)\:\%\:n = a \cdot x\:\%\:n - a \cdot y\:\%\:n = 0\$, and we follow that \$n  \mid  a \cdot (x - y)\$, i.e., \$n\$ divides \$a \cdot (x - y)\$ evenly. Since \$n\$ shares no prime divisors with \$a\$, this means that \$n  \mid  x - y\$. Finally, because \$-n < x - y < n\$, we conclude that \$x = y\$. This shows that the products \$a \cdot_n 0, \dots, a \cdot_n (n - 1)\$ are all different elements of \$Z_n\$. Since \$Z_n\$ has exactly \$n\$ elements, one (and exactly one) of those products must be equal to \$1\$, i.e., there is a *unique* \$b\$ in \$Z_n\$ such that \$a \cdot_n b = 1\$.

Conversely, fix \$n > 1\$ and let \$a\$ be an element of \$Z_n\$ that is *not* coprime to \$n\$. In this case, there is a prime \$p\$ such that \$p  \mid  a\$ and \$p  \mid  n\$. If \$a\$ admitted a multiplicative inverse modulo \$n\$ (let's call it \$b\$), we'd have that \$a \cdot_n b = 1\$, meaning that \$a \cdot b\:\%\:n = 1\$ and, therefore, \$(a \cdot b - 1)\:\%\:n = a \cdot b\:\%\:n - 1 = 0\$, so \$n  \mid  a \cdot b - 1\$. Since \$p  \mid  a\$, we follow that \$p  \mid  a \cdot b\$. On the other hand, since \$p  \mid  n\$, we also follow that \$p  \mid  a \cdot b - 1\$.  This way, \$p  \mid  (a \cdot b) - (a \cdot b - 1) = 1\$, which contradicts the assumption that \$p\$ is a prime number.

This proves that the following statements are equivalent when \$n > 1\$.

- \$a\$ and \$n\$ are coprime.
- \$a\$ admits a multiplicative inverse modulo \$n\$.
- \$a\$ admits a *unique* multiplicative inverse modulo \$n\$.

#### How it works

For each pair of integers \$a\$ and \$b\$ in \$Z_n\$, the integer \$k := a \cdot n + b\$ is unique; in fact, \$a\$ and \$b\$ are quotient and remainder of \$k\$ divided by \$n\$, i.e., given \$k\$, we can recover \$a = k/n\$ and \$b = k\:\%\: n\$, where \$/\$ denotes *integer* division. Finally, since \$a ≤ n - 1\$ and \$b ≤ n - 1\$, \$k\$ is an element of \$Z_{n^2}\$; in fact, \$k ≤ (n - 1) \cdot n + (n - 1) = n^2 - 1\$.

As noted above, if \$a\$ and \$n\$ are coprime, there will be a unique \$b\$ such that \$a \cdot b\:\%\:n = 1\$, i.e., there will be a unique \$k\$ such that \$k / n = a\$ and \$k / n \cdot k\:\%\:n = (k / n) \cdot (k\:\%\:n)\:\%\:n = 1\$, so the generated list will contain \$a\$ exactly once.

Conversely, if \$a\$ and \$n\$ are *not* coprime, the condition \$k / n \cdot k\:\%\:n = 1\$ will be false for all values of \$k\$ such that \$a = k / n\$, so the generated list will *not* contain \$a\$.

This proves that the list the *lambda* returns will contain all of \$n\$'s coprimes in \$Z_n\$ exactly once.

Comment: "GCD? Where we're going, we don't need GCD."

Comment: Woah. That's all I wanted to write, but apparently I needed 15 characters. Still, woah. Great job.

Answer (score 24):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
gRỊT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@58e9HB3V8j/w@2Pmta4//9vqKNgpKNgrKNgpqNgaADkgLApUMQAAA)

#### How it works

```
gRỊT  Main link. Argument: n

 R    Range; yield [1, ..., n].
g     Compute the GCD of n and each k in [1, ..., n].
  Ị   Insignificant; return 1 for GCDs less or equal to 1.
   T  Truth; yield the indices of all truthy elements.
```

Comment: Coding in this language takes some `gRỊT`

Comment: I managed to (ab)use the "Minimum link value" quick (`ÐṂ`) in order to get [3 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143985/59487).

Answer (score 14):

### Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
Range@#~GCD~#~Position~1&
```

Slightly weird output format, where each result is wrapped in a separate list, e.g. `{{1}, {3}, {7}, {9}}`. If that's not okay, I've got two solutions at 30 bytes:

```
Select[Range[x=#],#~GCD~x<2&]&
#&@@@Range@#~GCD~#~Position~1&
```

Mathematica actually has `CoprimeQ` but that's way too long.

Comment: What does `Q` mean in `CoprimeQ`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien "question" I guess. All decision problem built-ins end in Q like `EvenQ`, `PrimeQ` or `SubsetQ`.

Answer (score 10):

## Python, <s>93</s> <s>82</s> 74 bytes

```py
f=lambda a,b:f(b,a%b)if b else a<2
lambda c:[i for i in range(c)if f(i,c)]
```

`f` recursively checks for coprimes, and the second lambda generates them.  Outputs a list.

Answer (score 10):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 4 bytes

Code:

```
ƒN¿–
```

Explanation:

```
ƒ       # For N in the range [0, input]..
 N¿     #   Compute the GCD of N and the input
   –    #   If 1, print N with a newline
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/2sable#@39skt@h/Y8aJv//b2wAAA)

Comment: Good job (almost) beating Dennis. (few minutes late though).

Answer (score 7):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 8 bytes

```
;╗R`╜┤`░
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#ARUA6v//O@KVl1Jg4pWc4pSkYOKWkf//MTA)

Explanation:

```
;╗R`╜┤`░
  R`  `░  elements of range(1, n+1) where
;╗  ╜     n and the element
     ┤    are coprime
```

Comment: I believe you can just do `range(1, n)` if that saves any bytes.

Comment: @ETHproductions It doesn't. The two options are `R` (`range(1, n+1)`) and `r` (`range(n)`). Since they're equivalent, I chose `R` (since I accidentally hit caps lock while writing the code).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I didn't see an instruction that seemed dedicated to incrementing, but I thought there might have been one anyway

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
:GZd1=f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2/lHpViaJv2/7@RAQA)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>64</s> 61 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @user81655*

```
n=>[...Array(n).keys()].filter(b=>(g=a=>b?g(b,b=a%b):a<2)(n))
```

#### Test snippet

```js
f=n=>[...Array(n).keys()].filter(b=>(g=a=>b?g(b,b=a%b):a<2)(n))

for(var i = 2; i < 50; i++) console.log(i + ":", `[${ f(i) }]`);
```

Comment: Can't you swap `a==` with `a<2`?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Not sure, `a` might be 0 at some point. I'll have to check

Comment: You could move the GCD function into the `filter` to remove the need to receive a `b` parameter: `...keys()].filter(b=>(g=a=>b?g(b,b=a%b):a<2)(n))`

Comment: @user81655 That's great, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB/Octave, 22 bytes

```
@(n)find(gcd(1:n,n)<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaeZlpmXopGenKJhaJWnk6dpY6T5PzGvWMPIQPM/AA)

Answer (score 6):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
p
[#
`B
&~xr1
NnEi
```

This works by computing the prime factorization of every number in the range and checking whether it intersects that of the input (Jellyfish doesn't have a gcd builtin yet).
For golfing reasons, the output is in descending order.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@1/AFa3MleDEpVZXUWTI5Zfnmvn/v5EBAA)

### Explanation

First off, `i` is evaluated input; for input `10`, the value of the `i`-cell is `10`.

```
r1
i
```

Here `r` (range) is applied to the input and 1.
Because the input is greater than 1, the range is in descending order; for input `10`, this gives `[9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]`.

```
[#
`B
&~x
Nn
```

This part is one big function, which is evaluated on `i` and the above range.

```
~x
n
```

Intersection (`n`) of prime factors (`x`).

```
&~x
Nn
```

Is it empty? (`N`)

```
`
&~x
Nn
```

Thread to level 0, testing for each element of the range.

```
[#
`B
&~x
Nn
```

Filter (`#`) the range with respect to this list of booleans.
The function produced by `[` wants to use the argument to `#` as its own argument, so we put a `B` to block `#` from getting any arguments.
Otherwise, the value of the `~`-cell would be used as the argument of the big function.
Finally, `p` prints the result.

Answer (score 5):

## Stacked, noncompeting, <s>24</s> 21 bytes

Saved 3 bytes, inspired by [Borsunho's ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104675/31957). (`1 eq` to `2<`)

```
{!n:>1+:n gcd 2<keep}
```

[Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html)

This is an n-lambda that takes a single argument and yields the array.

```
{!n:>1+:n gcd 2<keep}
{!                  }  n-lambda
  n                    push n
   :>                  range [0, n)
     1+                range [1, n]
       :               duplicate
        n gcd          element-wise gcd with n
              2<       element-wise equality with 1
                       this yields the range [1, n] and a boolean mask of coprime numbers
                keep   then, we simply apply the mask to the range and keep coprimes.
```

Comment: Why is this noncompeting?

Comment: @ZacharyT mainly, `keep` wasn't working nicely.

Answer (score 5):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 14 bytes

```
{:X{Xmff%:*},}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#izZSMFYwUTBVMFMwNFAwAiJTBWOD2P/VVhHVEblpaapWWrU6tf9VrQr@AwA)

#### Explanation

We don't need to check all possible divisors of `a` and `b` to test whether they're coprime. It's sufficient to look at whether any of the prime factors of `b` divides `a`.

```
:X     e# Store the input in X.
{      e# Filter the list [0 1 ... X-1] by the results of this block...
  Xmf  e#   Get the prime factors of X.
  f%   e#   Take the current value modulo each of those prime factors.
  :*   e#   Multiply the results. Iff any of them divide the current
       e#   value, there's a 0 in the list, and the result of the product
       e#   is also 0, dropping the value from the resulting list.
},
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
Pick[r=Range@#,r~GCD~#,1]&
```

Comment: Ohhhh, I've been looking for something like Pick. I guess now I'm glad I didn't find it, though. ;) But it should be very useful for future challenges.

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL, 10 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429).

```
0~⍨⍳×1=⊢∨⍳
```

Explanation (input `n`):

```
0~⍨⍳×1=⊢∨⍳
         ⍳ - 1 ... n (Thus, ⎕IO is 1)
       ⊢∨  - Each GCD'd by n
     1=    - Test equality with 1 on each element
   ⍳×      - multiplied by its index
0~⍨        - without 0.
```

Comment: I love the way APL code looks like the face you make when you read it. `⍨`

Comment: Yep, and it demolishes almost every not code-golf-oriented language. :).

Comment: Why only "might" work?

Comment: I'm just going to assume it works.

Comment: @ZacharyT why can't you test it? When I paste it into try-apl.org, it errors with invalid token.

Comment: This doesn't work on tryapl.org.

Comment: I don't have Dyalog.

Comment: @ZacharyT You can test on try-apl.org.

Comment: It's v16. Won't work.

Comment: Those 6 characters are actually [14 bytes in UTF-8](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2262%27UTF-8%27%u2395UCS%27%u23781%3D%u22A2%u2228%u2373%27&run) or 12 bytes in UTF-16 (try `80⎕DR'⍸1=⊢∨⍳'`). You may want to link to [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429).

Comment: Thank's, I'll revert it to the old version to save 2 bytes.

Comment: There. It's changed to the 10 byte version.

Comment: @ZacharyT How did you even get a hold of version 16.0?

Comment: Ugh. I was being insane. Following your suggestion from a while back. Thinking it was released like an idiot.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 20 bytes

```
{grep 2>* gcd$_,^$_}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 23 bytes

```julia
!n=1÷gcd.(1:n,n)|>find
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#@6@YZ2t4eHt6coqehqFVnk6eZo1dWmZeyv@0/CKFPIXMPAUNIx0FYx0FMx0FQwMdBSMQNgWKGGhycToUFGXmlaRpKKkapSjo2imoFsfkKeko5OkoKOZpcqUCTQEA)

Comment: julia 1.0+ version: `!n=findall(gcd.(1:n,n).<2)` - no `find` and `findall` needs boolean.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
>.$p'(e:A*?),
```

This is a function that takes *N* as input, and [generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/62131) all integers less than and coprime to it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@29VbaenUqCukWrlqGWvqVObVv7/v7EBAA) As is often the case in Brachylog, this has had extra code added to make the function into a full program; Brachylog's interpreter, if given a function rather than a full program, will run it but not print the output, which means you can't really observe its workings.

Explanation:

A Brachylog program is a chain of constraints; typically, the LHS of one constraint is the RHS of the next.

```
>.$p'(e:A*?),
>              The input is greater than
 .             the output, whose
  $p           prime factorisation does
    '(     )   not obey the following constraint:
      e        it has an element which
       :A*     can be multiplied by something to
          ?    produce the input.
            ,  (This comma turns off an unwanted implicit constraint.)
```

Golfed down three characters by realising there's no reason to check to see if the common factor (which is already known to be a prime factor of the output) is a *prime* factor of the input. We already know it's prime, so we can just check if it's a factor. I'm pleasantly surprised here that `:A*?` doesn't send the interpreter into an infinite loop *and* doesn't allow a non-integer value for *A*, but as the interpreter does what I want, I'll take it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) `-f`, <s>9</s> <s>8</s> <s>5</s> 2 bytes

```
jN
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ak4=&input=ODgKLWY=)

- 2 bytes saved thanks to [ETH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) pointing out a brainfart, which led to another byte saved.

Comment: You could do `o f_jU`

Comment: Thanks, @ETHproductions. Don't know what I was thinking here! Must've been one of those (many) moments when I forget `j` can also be used to test if 2 numbers are co-prime.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
xSelect[Range@x,x~CoprimeQ~#&]
```

Contains U+F4A1

Comment: What's the unprintable do?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk introduces an unnamed function with a named argument. it's rendered as an arrow in Mma.

Comment: @MartinEnder oh, cool.

Comment: U+F4A1 is a private use character. As Martin said, it's rendered as an arrow in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 27 bytes

```
f n=[k|k<-[1..n],gcd n k<2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkGcbnV2TbaMbbainlxerk56copCnkG1jFPs/NzEzT8FWoaC0JLikyCdPpTgjv1xFIU3ByOA/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [memes](https://github.com/ineternet/memes), 11 bytes

Uses UTF-8 encoding.

```
d`}}]i=1?ip
```

Explanation:

```
d     Set program to not output result
`}    Loop next input-times
}]i   GCD of input and loop index
=1?   Is it equal to 1? If yes,
ip    Print out loop index
```

`}` accesses the next input item, but last input is looped through when given, so inputting `6` will result as `6 6 6 6 6 ...` in STDIN, making it possible for reading two outputs from one.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
Lʒ¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f59SkQ/v//zc2AAA)

Has new features.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>36</s>34

```
->n{n.times{|i|p i if i.gcd(n)<2}}
```

Admittedly, this isn`t a very *inspired* answer.

2 bytes saved thanks to Conor O'Brien.

Comment: You can shave off two bytes by removing parentheses around `(n)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

Imports gcd instead of writing a new lambda for it. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@ZW5BfVKKQm1iSwVVhm5OYm5SSqJBsFZ2pkJZfpJCpkJmnUJSYl56qkayZmQZWppeenKKRrJOpaWMUy1VQlJlXolGhYWigqfn/PwA)

```python
import math
lambda c:[i for i in range(c)if math.gcd(c,i)<2]
```

Comment: I don't think you _can_ golf this more. Importing gcd directly or math as m both add bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 30 bytes

```
n->filter(x->(gcd(n,x)<2),1:n)
```

Anonymous function. `filter` removes elements from a list that aren't truthy according to a function.

In this case, the function is `x->(gcd(n,x)<2)` (true if the gcd of the input and the list element is less than 2).  The list is the range `1:n`.

Comment: -2bytes: `x->(gcd(n,x)<2)` could be `x->gcd(n,x)<2`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 27 bytes

```
n->[k|k<-[1..n],gcd(k,n)<2]
```

This uses the set-notation introduced in version 2.6.0 (2013). In earlier versions, four more bytes were needed:

```
n->select(k->gcd(k,n)<2,[1..n])
```

would be needed.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk The same as most of these submissions -- make a range from 1 to n (`[1..n]`), check if gcd is 1 (`gcd(n,k)<2`), return the numbers with this property. The `->` is function/closure notation, shorter by 2 bytes than normal function syntax and `[...|...<-...,...]` is the set notation explained in the answer (see section 2.3.14 in the User's Manual, or search for `<-`).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
GN¿–
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f3e/Q/kcNk///NzYAAA)

How it works

```
     # implicit input
G    # for N in range(1..input)
 N   # push N
  ¿  # gcd(input, N)
   – # if 1, print N
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 54 bytes

```c
k;f(n){for(k=0;++k/n<n;k/n*k%n-1||printf("%u ",k/n));}
```

This is a port of [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104681/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU3RCsIwDHxuvyIMBu3a4TbRB@O@RH2QQWWUxTK2p63fXlNQH5LL3SW5oX4NQ0oenSK9ufesfN@gMf5AV0LulS@pbvc9zCMtThXlCoVlXWuMiSWYniMpLTcpMltuD@hhg87C0cLZQttY6HKdWGFsIKKUgpNA5YMq8P6CjAjBGC0FfxL/tG69cB67Gll26jv8/DsVmUcZ0wc)

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##NU1BCsIwEDwnr1gCgaRNsFb04NKXqAepREpwDaU9lbw9bqAeltmZ2dkZ/XscS4kYDNktfGcTB2oIvY/4SvNESzDxQE3U5JReQTlm1mIubMHnOZGxcpOisuX2gAE26B2cHFwcHDsHfZ0zK4wdZJRScAuYGmgS3y/IiJDa1krBn8TeqnS/XrmPXYssB7Mvf/9OqvIsc/kB). It outputs in reverse order (allowed by the author), and clutters stdin and stderr

Answer (score 2):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 65 bytes

```
> Input
> 1
>> (1]
>> L⊓1
>> L=2
>> Select∘ 4 5 3
>> Output 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMtOwZDLzk5BwzAWRPk86poM5vvYGoGo4NSc1OSSRx0zFEwUTBWMQUL@pSVAfQpm//8bGwAA)

Uses the [recently implemented](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/commit/36e87fb697076db347602b521b30b054471a9991) `Select∘` command.

### How it works

The entire program is built from lines **4**, **5** and **6**

```
>> L⊓1
>> L=2
>> Select∘ 4 5 3
```

This is the first use of any of the three `Select` statements, this time using the `Select∘` statement. All forms of the `Select` statements take **n** line references as arguments. The last number references the array to select from (let's say \$A\$), and the others reference the functions to iterate over that array (i.e the array of functions, \$B\$). However, they differ as follows:

- `Select∧` - Only select elements which are truthy under all functions in \$B\$:

$$R := [x \in A \: | \: f(x) \top, \forall f \in B]$$

- `Select∨` - Only select elements which are truthy under any function in \$B\$

$$R := [x \in A \: | \: f(x) \top, \exists f \in B]$$

- `Select∘` - Only select elements which, when all functions in \$B\$ are [composed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) together, are truthy under this new function:

$$\text{Let }B := [f(x), g(x), h(x)]$$
$$R := [x \in A \: | \: h(g(f(x))) \: \top]$$

In this program, we can define \$A := [1, 2, ..., \alpha-1, \alpha]\$, where \$\alpha\$ is the input. We then define line **4** (`>> L⊓1`) as \$f(x) = \gcd(x, \alpha)\$ and line **5** (`>> L=2`) as \$g(x) := (x = 1)\$. Finally, we can define \$B = [f(x), g(x)]\$. This sets us up for the select statement as shown above.

When we encounter the `Select∘` statement, we take \$R\$ (the final array) as defined by the third relationship above. To make things slightly easer, we'll define

\begin{align}
h(x) & := g(f(x)) \\
 & := gcd(x, \alpha) = 1
\end{align}

\$R\$ is then equal to the array where \$\forall x \in R\$, \$h(x) \: \top\$. Finally, on the last line, we output \$R\$.

#### Shorter version, 56 bytes

```
> Input
> 1
>> (1]
>> L⟂1
>> Select∘ 4 3
>> Output 5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMtOwZDLzk5BwzAWRPk8mt8E5gen5qQmlzzqmKFgomAMEvAvLQEqVzD9/9/YAAA)

This is much less interesting as it uses the [co-prime builtin](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/blob/master/whispers.py#L507). In this case, any of the three select statements can be used.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
'?ġ1=
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%27%3F%C4%A11%3D&inputs=10&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
       # Implicit input
'      # Apply function for n in range [0,input) and filter:
 ?     #   Input
  ġ    #   GCD of input and current number
   1=  #   Equal to 1?
       # Implicit output
```

Comment: [This can be 4 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCInP8Sh4bmFIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) or [3.375 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiJz/EoeG5hSIsIiIsIjEwIl0=) now

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 53 bytes

```
n=>[for(i of Array(n*n).keys())if(i*(i=i/n|0)%n==1)i]
```

Port of @Dennis's amazing Python answer. 60 bytes in ES6:

```
n=>[...Array(n*n)].map((_,i)=>i/n|0).filter((i,j)=>i*j%n==1)
```

Similar idea of looking for the multiplicative inverse, also 60 bytes in ES6:

```
n=>[...Array(n).keys()].filter((i,_,a)=>a.some(j=>i*j%n==1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
x1iLQ
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=x1iLQ&input=30&debug=0)

### How it works

Note that Pyth uses 0-indexing.

```
x1iLQ   Q = eval(input())

x1iLQQ  implicit Q at the end
  iLQQ  [gcd(Q,0), gcd(Q,1), ..., gcd(Q,Q-1)]
x1      all occurences of 1 in the above list (return their indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
§foε⌋ḣ
```

-1 thanks @Leo!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DytPxzWx/1dD/csfj////GBgA)

#### Explanation

```
        -- implicit input N
§f   ḣ  -- filter the range [1..N] with
  oε⌋   --   is gcd(N,·) at most 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 99 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
g(a,b){return b>0?g(b,a%b):a;}c(n,i){for(i=1;i<n;i++)g(n,i)<2?printf("%i ",i):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc29DoMgHATwWZ@C2JhApY2adBE/HqRxAFT8JxYail2Mz07RodNdfjecvCkp/QW0XNZhRPXHDQuI@9z@7SAwQWKFORVks6NbrUaizTuFBeWpIBVnu8SaAtkmYzE0BYNaM8gyok6uy@5tQbsJJymgJEiVs90HQS8OGh@FWyUpkjO311C/z55scXQMGjWIOwP45KInLI7CW4jd@/LxAw)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 98 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;n->{Set r=new HashSet();for(int i=0;++i/n<n;)r.add(i/n*i%n==1?i/n:1);return r;}
```

Port of [*@Dennis*' amazing Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104681/52210).

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jY6xTsMwEIb3PMUtSHarOG0RHTCBlYUKqSNicB2HOiTnyLkUVVWePVxa9iDZsv9f39lfZU4mDa3DqvgefdOGSFBxp3rytVpoAMgyeDdchxLo6OBwJpfa0CMlia1N18Gb8XhJADySi6WxDnZTBNg7Aiu4BpSam4E3rx0g5DBi@nyZiJij@4FX0x05CanLEK8zPl/p5dJn@IRaRmWKQnBY@DvM8/ULXx/XUkdHfUSIehj17fW2P9TeQkeG@DgFX0DDgmJP0ePXxycYebObtKFhk@n7KYirJGufO3KNCj2plmeoRtEoVFZs5BxxP0tsZ4n1ahbZ/AN5mJf9e2VIhvEX)

```java
import java.util.*;     // Required import for Set and HashSet

n->{                    // Method with integer parameter and Set return-type
  Set r=new HashSet();  //  Result-Set
  for(int i=0;          //  Index-integer (starting at 0)
      ++i/n<n;)         //  Loop as long as `i/n` is smaller than `n`
                        //  (starting `i` at 1 by first increasing it by 1 with `++i`)
    r.add(i/n           //   If `i/n`,
          *i%n          //   multiplied by `i` modulo-`n`,
              ==1?      //   is exactly 1:
           i/n          //    Add `i/n` to the Set
          :             //   Else:
           1            //    Add 1 to the Set
  );                    //  End of loop
  return r;             //  Return the result-Set
}                       // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

```
S⁇
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P/hRY/v//8YGAA)

I seem to have [outgolfed myself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143985/59487).

```
S⁇  - Full program.

 ⁇  - Filter-Keep (operates on the automatically generated range).
S   - Check if the input and the current element are coprime.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C <del>177</del> ,  <del>150</del>  , <del>135</del> , 102 bytes

Not very golfy but...

```
p,i,t,x,y,N;f(n){
int A[9]={};
for(i=0,N=n;p<n;n/=p){
for(p=2+(n&1);n%p;)p+=2;
A[i++]=p;
}
for(y=0;y++<N;){
for(i=t=0;x=A[i++];)
t|=!(y%x);
if(!t)printf("%d ",y);
}
}
```

EDIT: one line 150

```
p,i,t,x,y,N;f(n){int A[9]={};for(i=0,N=n;p<n;n/=A[i++]=p)for(p=2+(n&1);n%p;)p+=2;for(y=0;y++<N;){for(i=t=0;x=A[i++];)t|=!(y%x);printf("\0 %d"+!t,y);}}
```

EDIT2:

```
f(n){int p,t,x,i=0,y=0,N=n,A[9]={};for(;p<n;n/=A[i++]=p)for(p=2;n%p;)p++;for(;y++<N;printf("\0 %d"+!t,y))for(i=t=0;x=A[i++];)t|=y%x<1;}
```

Stores array of primefactors of N,
Then prints numbers < N that don't divide those.

EDIT3:
Got rid of Array, recalulating primefactors instead

```
f(n){int p,t,i=0,N=n;for(;i++<N;printf("\0 %d"+!t,i))for(n=N,p=t=0;p<n;n/=p,t|=i%p<1)for(p=1;n%++p;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5NDoIwEIX3PUUlIWnTMRaIshhmwwG4ALIwKKYLxwbLCjk7tiZv972/8fgcx32fFOvVcZAeAjiy0BHj9J4VOmOaDv0c4aSyq5X5PTOHaNI6caYOPAWy6BtGPlEs@JLLfVP8uacCOTfGo8Ztf90cK72KtNT29SBJriVUcIHCQhl1hspuKFIyeeITdE2dTmixTqrt3aDRL@GjsiwWivkRlpmlRbHtPw)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can remove the newlines in C

Comment: [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY5BCoMwFET3OUUQhAR/aVRaFz/ZeIBcQFwU25Qsmn5sXKlnT6Mwu3m8menynqaUCCJ4sOhEkKv7zsIbhb6qdMC4bTT7EJ0oePkswEt5ANYEIBMzRtqivZqs2IwvSddnT6ZGW1YVocQ9fR4@CLmy7OH90I3c8LWBFu5QK2hybtCqHdk5nZlzXnfHBclWJ/rBjxJpiT9RFFnI5ldc5sAVsj39AQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 59 bytes

```
g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):(a>1)ort[#t]=i
f=n=>fort={}n>i++g(n,i)t
```

This defines the function `f`, which generates a list of all co-primes from `1` to `n`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/z/dViNRJ0nT1i7JPl0jSSdRNUnTSiPRzlAzv6gkWrkk1jaTK802z9YuDci3ra7Ns8vU1k7XyNPJ1Cz5X1CUmVeioaenl6ZhaKqp@R8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 28 bytes

```
n->[x|x<-[0..n],gcd(x,n)==1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifZvs/T9cuuqKmwkY32kBPLy9WJz05RaNCJ0/T1tYw9n9BUWZeiUaahrGBpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 149 bytes

```
	DEFINE('G(A,B)')
	N =INPUT
I	X =X + 1
	EQ(X,N)	:S(END)
	K =G(N,X)
	OUTPUT =EQ(K,1) X :(I)
G	T =REMDR(A,B)
	A =B
	B =T
	G =EQ(B) A	:F(G)S(RETURN)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsMwDEXRWfoKbZGoh4Z2CniIiWNMqNo6DnjOXJqh/49rsj0eh/v7HvvxudcKk5@jeu4Cj8ZJJwhKNupryxihkC10oR7Bv7kYFRhW9jo1tZANrKa0@dxy42SbWUwvVGjgKBigfck/pnSmEUayDsGRzQjh5E5ohGHmICsnn7ekgi1f6@36Bw)

Uses the Euclidean algorithm in the function `G` to calculate the GCD; prints values with newlines between them.

```
	DEFINE('G(A,B)')		;*let the interpreter know a function G is available
	N =INPUT			;*read input
I	X =X + 1			;*increment step
	EQ(X,N)	:S(END)			;*if X==N, end
	K =G(N,X)			;*K =GCD(N,X)
	OUTPUT =EQ(K,1) X :(I)		;*if K==1, output X. goto I
G	T =REMDR(A,B)			;*function body: euclidean algorithm
	A =B
	B =T
	G =EQ(B) A	:F(G)S(RETURN)	;*if B==0, G=A and return.
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 16 Bytes

```
C=:I.@(1:=]+.i.)
```

C for coprime.

#### How it works:

```
C=:                | Define the verb C
             i.    | Integers between 0 and n-1 inclusive
          ]+.      | GCD with n. Gets applied to each element of i.n
       1:=         | Test whether each element of the array is 1. If it is, put 1, otherwise 0
   I.              | Return the indexes of the 1s. If there are none (i.e., on input 1) returns 0.
```

Parenthesis and @ are just so it gets executed in the right order.

Step by step example:

```
    (]+.i.) 10
10 1 2 1 2 5 2 1 2 1

    (1:=]+.i.) 10
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1

    I.@(1:=]+.i.) 10
1 3 7 9

    C 10
1 3 7 9
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 35 bytes

```
@(!>@=1len inx 'fac#0fac#1).'rng1#0
```

Usage:

```
(@(!>@=1len inx 'fac#0fac#1).'rng1#0)3
```

Basically filters over a range from 1 to the input with a predicate:

- Find all factors of both the current mapped item and the input.
- Find the intersection of both arrays.
- Check if the result is of length 1. If the 2 numbers are coprime, then their factors' intersection set should only contain 1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

```julia
(n)->[k for k=1:n if gcd(n,k)==1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsIwFET3OcVQKCTwC01EF0KKR3CvXZTGX2LkK60Fbx/TDszmPZh5rq842F9elygTrnOULyv2WYtpulsCv2ckb8@CyJjGoIWS8d72eTOFCrQjHAgngm0JbuuxkNYolFw@@6auahfQdKiXu1QEIXD5MOohIf8B)

Comment: it is actually 30 bytes: `n->[k for k=1:n if gcd(n,k)<2]`

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 35 bytes

```scala
n=>BigInt(1)to n filter(_.gcd(n)<2)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gQvANTQjTmS6vqwmJpbc7g)

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 76 bytes (19 instrs)

```
void __mmixcall coprimes(octa n,
                         void *d, void (*__mmixcall f)(void *d, octa i));
```

(jelly xxd)

```
00000000: fe03 0004 c104 0000 f701 0000 2704 0401  “¤¡¥Ḋ¥¡¡ẋ¢¡¡'¥¥¢
00000010: 5a04 0003 f604 0003 f800 0000 c105 0400  Z¥¡¤ẇ¥¡¤ẏ¡¡¡Ḋ¦¥¡
00000020: c106 0000 1e06 0605 c106 0500 fe05 0006  Ḋ©¡¡œ©©¦Ḋ©¦¡“¦¡©
00000030: 5b05 fffd 2706 0601 4306 fff5 c106 0100  [¦”’'©©¢C©”ṫḊ©¢¡
00000040: c107 0400 bf05 0200 f1ff fff1            Ḋ¬¥¡Ḃ¦£¡ȯ””ȯ
```

Disassembly and explanation

```
coprimes    GET    $3,rJ        // savedj = rJ
            SET    $4,$0        // i = n
            PUT    rD,0         // zero out hidiv register
0H          SUBU   $4,$4,1      // loop: i--
            PBNZ   $4,1F        // iflikely(i) goto continuation
            PUT    rJ,$3        // rJ = savedj
            POP    0,0          // return
1H          SET    $5,$4        // continuation: p = i
            SET    $6,$0        // q = n
1H          DIVU   $6,$6,$5     // gcd: q:rR = rD:q /% p
            SET    $6,$5        // q = p
            GET    $5,rR        // p = rR
            PBNZ   $5,1B        // iflikely(p) goto gcd
            SUBU   $6,$6,1      // q--
            BZ     $6,0B        // if(!q) goto loop
            SET    $6,$1        // fa1 = d
            SET    $7,$4        // fa2 = i
            PUSHGO $5,$2,0      // f(fa1,fa2)
            JMP    0B           // goto loop
```

I don't have a good way to output a sequence, so I just went with the tried and true callback method. Works for any `n` from \$1\$ to \$2^{63}-1\$.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 40 bytes

```
[ dup iota [ gcd nip 1 = ] with filter ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY27CgIxFER7v2K@QPaBFoq12NiIVUgRszduMHs3Zu8qIn57jAjDNOcM44yVMeXz6XDcb3CjxBQw0X0mtjTBj4iJRF4xeRYMRvqlm9mKH3nCdvFGgxZr1BWakhXaCp@s0M2xbMVA4Wo7sI@osYPG00sP54NQgs6DicVQuISCFOL/RaM0pUDmQeAfImP7/AU)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 31 bytes

```arturo
$->n[select..1n'x->1=gcd@[x,n]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?AdVtFc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
rG1Ĩ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FkuL3A2PrFhSnJRcDBVZsM6Iy5jLjMvQgMvIlMvYACIKAA)

```
r       Range from 0 to input - 1
 G      GCD with input
  1Ĩ    Find indices of 1s (0-indexed)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `v`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
æĠḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT1maWx0ZXIlMjBkeWFkaWNfZ2NkJTIwZXF1YWxzX29uZSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTMwJmZsYWdzPXY=)

##### Explanation

```python
æĠḅ  # Implicit input
æ    # Filter (implicit cast to range) by:
 Ġ   #  GCD of this number and the input
  ḅ  #  Equals one?
     # Implicit output
```